# mockito Powermockito object mapper

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am using the following to mock `writeValueAsString(any())` method in the object mapper. However the `writeValueAsString` method is not getting mocked and getting called in the method I am testing in the application.

I did try `spy` as well but it did not work. Is there any other suggestion.

Trial 1

```
ObjectMapper mockOM = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
when(mockOM.writeValueAsString(any())).thenReturn(t);
```

Trial 2

```
ObjectMapper mockOM = Mockito.spy(new ObjectMapper());
when(mockOM.writeValueAsString(any())).thenReturn(t);
```

`t` is a string here.

Any help will be great

Comment: can you show your test code

Comment: We need your tests code to see if you can either just set the `value` so the called functions works or otherwise you might be forced to use PowerMockito.

Comment: ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: sorry for the bad code ... actually my code looks like below

function(){
////....


ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

//

Logger.info(“Log object”+ om.writeValueAsString(ClassObject))

//
}

I am mocking all the objects in the function that are being used in the method , Is it because the logger function I am using for  calling the writeValueAsString through the Object Mapper om?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into the same issue once.
The following solved it for me:

```
ObjectMapper mockOM = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
// old: when(mockOM.writeValueAsString(any())).thenReturn(t);
doReturn(t).when(mockOM).writeValueAsString(any());
```

Comment: actually my code looks like below function(){ ////.... ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); // Logger.info(“Log object”+ om.writeValueAsString(ClassObject)) // } I am mocking all the objects in the function that are being used in the method , Is it because the logger function I am using for calling the writeValueAsString through the Object Mapper om?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Maybe you could format your code as such in the comment so it's easier to read your comment. Or add your test code to the question